# build function which takes values from above row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, rows, shift

i have the following dataframe:

[image]

i want to build func to apply on column 'c' that will take the subtraction from columns 'd' and 'u' and add the value from the row above in column 'c'.
so the the table will look as follow:

[image]

for example in row number 2 the calculation will be: 44.37 - 0 + 149.77 = 194.14
            in row number 4 the calculation will be 11.09 - 6.45 + 210.78 = 215.42
and so on.. 
i tried to build function using iloc with while loop or shift but non of them worked as i got an error:

("'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'iloc'", 'occurred at index 0')

("'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'shift'", 'occurred at index 0')

any idea how to make this function will be great.

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can apply direct subtraction of columns and use cummulative sum to add values

```
        d   u
0   0.000   149.75
1   0.000   44.37
2   0.000   16.64
3   6.450   11.09
4   77.345  5.54
5   64.520  16.40

df1['C'] = (df1['u'] - df1['d']).cumsum()
```

OUt:

```
    d   u   c
0   0.000   149.75  149.750
1   0.000   44.37   194.120
2   0.000   16.64   210.760
3   6.450   11.09   215.400
4   77.345  5.54    143.595
5   64.520  16.40   95.475
```